# Magento 2 Unable to redirect http to https when using multistore

Tags: magento2, redirect, htaccess, https

I am unable to redirect HTTP to https when using a multistore option. Anyone else using more than one store and has the http->https auto redirection working from `.htaccess`?

Comment: Please add your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple issues. For once port 80 was only accessible from a specific address I changed that in the firewall. Also the configuration mentioned is not redirecting for me even though I set **Use Secure URLs on Storefront** to Yes. The way I solved the issue is that I set the https url for base urls and base urls ( secure )

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this via database:
**->** Go to `core_config_data` table
**->** in `base_secure` or `unsecure` url change http to https
Secondly, check if your server has SSL Certification.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

Magento has default functionality for set `secure(https)` and `unsecure(http)` url.

Before update bellow setting backup `core_config_data` table.

Go to `Store-> Configuration-> General-> Web->Baseurl(secures)` and 
update `http` to `https`.

Update the value of `Use Secure URLs on Storefront` to `Yes`.

Refresh cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`.